# Animation becomes faster and faster every time I run it again

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a simple animation, it's just a cube, which can be rotated in different directions.

The issue is when I click run button then animation becomes faster and faster every time (try to click run several times). I suppose there is a problem with gl_draw() function, but why is that and how I can simply fix it?

```
function gl_draw() {
// set the color to transparent
gl_ctx.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
// enable Depth buffer test and set depth buffer comparison function
gl_ctx.enable(gl_ctx.DEPTH_TEST);
gl_ctx.depthFunc(gl_ctx.LEQUAL);

// set the clear value for the depth buffer to 1
gl_ctx.clearDepth(1.0);

var timeOld = 0;

var animate = function (time) {
  var dAngle = rotationSpeed * (time - timeOld);

  if (X) {
     MATRIX.rotateX(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
  }
  if (Y) {
     MATRIX.rotateY(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
  }
  if (Z) {
     MATRIX.rotateZ(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
  }

  timeOld = time;

  // set the drawing area on the canvas and clear it
  gl_ctx.viewport(0.0, 0.0, gl_canvas.width, gl_canvas.height);
  gl_ctx.clear(gl_ctx.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl_ctx.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  // set projection matrix. _matrixProjection is not set yet.
  // It is a javascript array of 1 dimension with 16 floats
  gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_PosMatrix, false, _matrixProjection);
  gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_MovMatrix, false, _matrixMovement);
  gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_ViewMatrix, false, _matrixView);
  // drawing is here - use these points for next drawing
  // gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(variable, dimension, type, normalize, total vertex size in bytes, offset)
  gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(_position, 3, gl_ctx.FLOAT, false, 4*(3+3), 0);
  gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(_color, 3, gl_ctx.FLOAT, false, 4*(3+3), 3*4);

  gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleVertexBuffer);
  gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleFacesBuffer);

  // draw the triangle
  //gl_ctx.drawElements(gl_ctx.TRIANGLES, 3, gl_ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

  // draw cube
  gl_ctx.drawElements(gl_ctx.TRIANGLES, 6*2*3, gl_ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

  // drawing is finished - show the render
  gl_ctx.flush();
  // redraws the scene as soon as ready
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};

// launch animate for the first time
animate(0);

}
```

Full code is here:

```js
var gl_canvas;
var gl_ctx;
var _triangleVertexBuffer;
var _triangleFacesBuffer;
var _position;
var _color;
var _PosMatrix;
var _MovMatrix;
var _ViewMatrix;
var _matrixProjection;
var _matrixMovement;
var _matrixView;

var rotationSpeed = 0.001;
var zoomRatio = -6;

var X, Y, Z;

function runWebGL () {
   getRotation();
   gl_canvas = document.getElementById("glcanvas");
   gl_ctx = gl_getContext(gl_canvas);
   gl_initShaders();
   gl_initBuffers();
   gl_setMatrix();
   gl_draw();
}

function getRotation() {
   X = document.getElementById('rotateX').checked;
   Y = document.getElementById('rotateY').checked;
   Z = document.getElementById('rotateZ').checked;
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_getContext (canvas) {
   try {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
      ctx.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
      ctx.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
   } catch (e) {}

   if (!ctx) {
      document.write('Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser may not support it.')
   }
   return ctx;
}

// ==================================================================== //

// Declare the shaders. They are pieces of code compiled by WebGL and
// executed on the graphics device. They are written in GLSL.
function gl_initShaders () {
   // position of the point - 0. is Z and 1. is W
   // PosMatrix is uniform variable - its value is constant while rendering an object
   // MovMatrix is the movement matrix of the triangle
   // gl_position -> we move position with MovMatrix before projecting it
   var vertexShader = "\n\
      attribute vec3 position;\n\
      uniform mat4 PosMatrix;\n\
      uniform mat4 MovMatrix;\n\
      uniform mat4 ViewMatrix; \n\
      attribute vec3 color;\n\
      varying vec3 vColor;\n\
      void main(void) {\n\
         gl_Position = PosMatrix * ViewMatrix * MovMatrix * vec4(position, 1.);\n\
         vColor = color;\n\
      }";

   // set black color
   var fragmentShader = "\n\
      precision mediump float;\n\
      varying vec3 vColor;\n\
      void main(void) {\n\
         gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.);\n\
      }";

   // this function is used to compile a shader
   var getShader = function(source, type, typeString) {
      var shader = gl_ctx.createShader(type);
      gl_ctx.shaderSource(shader, source);
      gl_ctx.compileShader(shader);

      if (!gl_ctx.getShaderParameter(shader, gl_ctx.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
         alert('error in' + typeString);
         return false;
      }
      return shader;
   };

   // Compile the vertex and fragment shaders
   var shader_vertex = getShader(vertexShader, gl_ctx.VERTEX_SHADER, "VERTEX");
   var shader_fragment = getShader(fragmentShader, gl_ctx.FRAGMENT_SHADER, "FRAGMENT");


   // Create the Shader program.
   // Shader program is a combination of a vertex and fragment shaders.
   var SHADER_PROGRAM = gl_ctx.createProgram();
   gl_ctx.attachShader(SHADER_PROGRAM, shader_vertex);
   gl_ctx.attachShader(SHADER_PROGRAM, shader_fragment);


   // Linking of the shader program to the WebGL context - gl_ctx,
   // in order to match the shader variables to javascript variables
   gl_ctx.linkProgram(SHADER_PROGRAM);

   // Link PosMatrix\MovMatrix\ViewMatrix GLSL variables to
   // _PosMatrix\_MovMatrix\_ViewMatrix javascript variables
   // Uniforms do not need to be enabled like attributes
   _PosMatrix = gl_ctx.getUniformLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "PosMatrix");
   _MovMatrix = gl_ctx.getUniformLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "MovMatrix");
   _ViewMatrix = gl_ctx.getUniformLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "ViewMatrix");

   // position GLSL variable links to _position variable
   _position = gl_ctx.getAttribLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "position");    // *******
   // color GLSL variable links to _color variable
   _color = gl_ctx.getAttribLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "color");
   // enable GLSL attributes variables
   gl_ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(_position);
   gl_ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(_color);
   // linking is over - tells WebGL context to use SHADER_PROGRAM for rendering.
   gl_ctx.useProgram(SHADER_PROGRAM);
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_initBuffers () {
   // Point coordinates array of the triangle
//   var triangleVertices = [
//      -1, -1, 0,    // bottom left
//       0, 0, 1,      // submit color: blue
//       1, -1, 0,    // bottom right
//       1, 1, 1,      // submit color: white
//       1, 1, 0,     // top right
//       1, 0, 0       // submit color: red
//   ];
   var triangleVertices = [
      -1,-1,-1,
      0,0,0,
      1,-1,-1,
      1,0,0,
      1,1,-1,
      1,1,0,
      -1,1,-1,
      0,1,0,
      -1,-1,1,
      0,0,1,
      1,-1,1,
      1,0,1,
      1,1,1,
      1,1,1,
      -1,1,1,
      0,1,1
   ];


   // Building Vertex Buffer Object - WebGL vertex array
   _triangleVertexBuffer = gl_ctx.createBuffer();                // *******
   gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleVertexBuffer);
   gl_ctx.bufferData(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(triangleVertices), gl_ctx.STATIC_DRAW);


   // Triangle faces array
   // var triangleFaces = [0, 1, 2];
   var triangleFaces = [
      0,1,2,
      0,2,3,
      4,5,6,
      4,6,7,
      0,3,7,
      0,4,7,
      1,2,6,
      1,5,6,
      2,3,6,
      3,7,6,
      0,1,5,
      0,4,5
   ];

   _triangleFacesBuffer = gl_ctx.createBuffer();                     // *******
   gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleFacesBuffer);
   gl_ctx.bufferData(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(triangleFaces), gl_ctx.STATIC_DRAW);
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_setMatrix () {
   _matrixProjection = MATRIX.getProjection(40, gl_canvas.width/gl_canvas.height, 1, 100);
   _matrixMovement = MATRIX.getIdentityMatrix();
   _matrixView = MATRIX.getIdentityMatrix();

   MATRIX.translateZ(_matrixView, zoomRatio);
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_draw() {
   // set the color to transparent
   gl_ctx.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   // enable Depth buffer test and set depth buffer comparison function
   gl_ctx.enable(gl_ctx.DEPTH_TEST);
   gl_ctx.depthFunc(gl_ctx.LEQUAL);

   // set the clear value for the depth buffer to 1
   gl_ctx.clearDepth(1.0);

   var timeOld = 0;

   var animate = function (time) {
      var dAngle = rotationSpeed * (time - timeOld);

      if (X) {
         MATRIX.rotateX(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
      }
      if (Y) {
         MATRIX.rotateY(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
      }
      if (Z) {
         MATRIX.rotateZ(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
      }

      timeOld = time;

      // set the drawing area on the canvas and clear it
      gl_ctx.viewport(0.0, 0.0, gl_canvas.width, gl_canvas.height);
      gl_ctx.clear(gl_ctx.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl_ctx.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      // set projection matrix. _matrixProjection is not set yet.
      // It is a javascript array of 1 dimension with 16 floats
      gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_PosMatrix, false, _matrixProjection);
      gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_MovMatrix, false, _matrixMovement);
      gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_ViewMatrix, false, _matrixView);
      // drawing is here - use these points for next drawing
      // gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(variable, dimension, type, normalize, total vertex size in bytes, offset)
      gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(_position, 3, gl_ctx.FLOAT, false, 4*(3+3), 0);
      gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(_color, 3, gl_ctx.FLOAT, false, 4*(3+3), 3*4);

      gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleVertexBuffer);
      gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleFacesBuffer);

      // draw the triangle
      //gl_ctx.drawElements(gl_ctx.TRIANGLES, 3, gl_ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

      // draw cube
      gl_ctx.drawElements(gl_ctx.TRIANGLES, 6*2*3, gl_ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

      // drawing is finished - show the render
      gl_ctx.flush();
      // redraws the scene as soon as ready
      window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   };

   // launch animate for the first time
   animate(0);

}

var MATRIX = {
   degToRad: function(angle) {
      return (angle*Math.PI/180);
   },

   getProjection: function(angle, a, zMin, zMax) {
      var tan = Math.tan(MATRIX.degToRad(0.5*angle)),
         A=-(zMax+zMin)/(zMax-zMin),
            B=(-2*zMax*zMin)/(zMax-zMin);

      return [
          .5/tan,          0,   0,    0,
               0,   .5*a/tan,   0,    0,
               0,          0,   A,   -1,
               0,          0,   B,    0
      ]
   },

   getIdentityMatrix: function () {
      return [
         1, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 1, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 1, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 1
      ];
   },

   // rotate movement matrix with angle around X axis
   rotateX: function(movMat, angle) {
      var sin = Math.sin(angle);
      var cos = Math.cos(angle);
      var matElem1 = movMat[1],
          matElem5 = movMat[5],
          matElem9 = movMat[9];

      movMat[1] = movMat[1]*cos - movMat[2]*sin;
      movMat[5] = movMat[5]*cos - movMat[6]*sin;
      movMat[9] = movMat[9]*cos - movMat[10]*sin;

      movMat[2] = movMat[2]*cos + matElem1*sin;
      movMat[6] = movMat[6]*cos + matElem5*sin;
      movMat[10] = movMat[10]*cos + matElem9*sin;
   },

   // rotate movement matrix with angle around Y axis
   rotateY: function(movMat, angle) {
      var sin = Math.sin(angle);
      var cos = Math.cos(angle);
      var matElem0 = movMat[0],
          matElem4 = movMat[4],
          matElem8 = movMat[8];

      movMat[0] = movMat[0]*cos + movMat[2]*sin;
      movMat[4] = movMat[4]*cos + movMat[6]*sin;
      movMat[8] = movMat[8]*cos + movMat[10]*sin;

      movMat[2] = movMat[2]*cos - matElem0*sin;
      movMat[6] = movMat[6]*cos - matElem4*sin;
      movMat[10] = movMat[10]*cos - matElem8*sin;
   },

   // rotate movement matrix with angle around Z axis
   rotateZ: function(movMat, angle) {
      var sin = Math.sin(angle);
      var cos = Math.cos(angle);
      var matElem0 = movMat[0],
          matElem4 = movMat[4],
          matElem8 = movMat[8];

      movMat[0] = movMat[0]*cos - movMat[1]*sin;
      movMat[4] = movMat[4]*cos - movMat[5]*sin;
      movMat[8] = movMat[8]*cos - movMat[9]*sin;

      movMat[1] = movMat[1]*cos + matElem0*sin;
      movMat[5] = movMat[5]*cos + matElem4*sin;
      movMat[9] = movMat[9]*cos + matElem8*sin;
   },

   // translate movement matrix by trans along Z axis
   translateZ: function (movMat, trans) {
      movMat[14] += trans;
   }
};
```

```css
canvas#glcanvas {
   border: 1px solid #66666D;
   background-color: #545469;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form class="rotationCheckboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" id="rotateX"> X Rotation
    <input type="checkbox" id="rotateY"> Y Rotation
    <input type="checkbox" id="rotateZ"> Z Rotation
    <input type="button" value="Run" onclick="runWebGL()"/>
  </form>
  <canvas id="glcanvas" width="500" height="300">HTML5 canvas is not supported</canvas>
  <br />
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that every time you click "run" you are stacking recursion of `animate`. One way you can deal with this is by clearing the previous animation (if there is one) every time you call `gl_draw`.

To do so, you will need to change 3 lines of code:

1. At the top level scope add a `var animation;`
2. at the top of `gl_draw` add this code:

   ```
   if (animation) {
     window.cancelAnimationFrame(animation)
   }
   ```
3. when you create the recursive loop set it to the `animation` variable

   ```
   animation = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
   ```

I also updated your snippet to reflect these changes - take a look:

```js
var gl_canvas;
var gl_ctx;
var animation;
var _triangleVertexBuffer;
var _triangleFacesBuffer;
var _position;
var _color;
var _PosMatrix;
var _MovMatrix;
var _ViewMatrix;
var _matrixProjection;
var _matrixMovement;
var _matrixView;

var rotationSpeed = 0.001;
var zoomRatio = -6;

var X, Y, Z;

function runWebGL () {
   getRotation();
   gl_canvas = document.getElementById("glcanvas");
   gl_ctx = gl_getContext(gl_canvas);
   gl_initShaders();
   gl_initBuffers();
   gl_setMatrix();
   gl_draw();
}

function getRotation() {
   X = document.getElementById('rotateX').checked;
   Y = document.getElementById('rotateY').checked;
   Z = document.getElementById('rotateZ').checked;
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_getContext (canvas) {
   try {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
      ctx.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
      ctx.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
   } catch (e) {}

   if (!ctx) {
      document.write('Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser may not support it.')
   }
   return ctx;
}

// ==================================================================== //

// Declare the shaders. They are pieces of code compiled by WebGL and
// executed on the graphics device. They are written in GLSL.
function gl_initShaders () {
   // position of the point - 0. is Z and 1. is W
   // PosMatrix is uniform variable - its value is constant while rendering an object
   // MovMatrix is the movement matrix of the triangle
   // gl_position -> we move position with MovMatrix before projecting it
   var vertexShader = "\n\
      attribute vec3 position;\n\
      uniform mat4 PosMatrix;\n\
      uniform mat4 MovMatrix;\n\
      uniform mat4 ViewMatrix; \n\
      attribute vec3 color;\n\
      varying vec3 vColor;\n\
      void main(void) {\n\
         gl_Position = PosMatrix * ViewMatrix * MovMatrix * vec4(position, 1.);\n\
         vColor = color;\n\
      }";

   // set black color
   var fragmentShader = "\n\
      precision mediump float;\n\
      varying vec3 vColor;\n\
      void main(void) {\n\
         gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.);\n\
      }";

   // this function is used to compile a shader
   var getShader = function(source, type, typeString) {
      var shader = gl_ctx.createShader(type);
      gl_ctx.shaderSource(shader, source);
      gl_ctx.compileShader(shader);

      if (!gl_ctx.getShaderParameter(shader, gl_ctx.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
         alert('error in' + typeString);
         return false;
      }
      return shader;
   };

   // Compile the vertex and fragment shaders
   var shader_vertex = getShader(vertexShader, gl_ctx.VERTEX_SHADER, "VERTEX");
   var shader_fragment = getShader(fragmentShader, gl_ctx.FRAGMENT_SHADER, "FRAGMENT");


   // Create the Shader program.
   // Shader program is a combination of a vertex and fragment shaders.
   var SHADER_PROGRAM = gl_ctx.createProgram();
   gl_ctx.attachShader(SHADER_PROGRAM, shader_vertex);
   gl_ctx.attachShader(SHADER_PROGRAM, shader_fragment);


   // Linking of the shader program to the WebGL context - gl_ctx,
   // in order to match the shader variables to javascript variables
   gl_ctx.linkProgram(SHADER_PROGRAM);

   // Link PosMatrix\MovMatrix\ViewMatrix GLSL variables to
   // _PosMatrix\_MovMatrix\_ViewMatrix javascript variables
   // Uniforms do not need to be enabled like attributes
   _PosMatrix = gl_ctx.getUniformLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "PosMatrix");
   _MovMatrix = gl_ctx.getUniformLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "MovMatrix");
   _ViewMatrix = gl_ctx.getUniformLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "ViewMatrix");

   // position GLSL variable links to _position variable
   _position = gl_ctx.getAttribLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "position");    // *******
   // color GLSL variable links to _color variable
   _color = gl_ctx.getAttribLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "color");
   // enable GLSL attributes variables
   gl_ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(_position);
   gl_ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(_color);
   // linking is over - tells WebGL context to use SHADER_PROGRAM for rendering.
   gl_ctx.useProgram(SHADER_PROGRAM);
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_initBuffers () {
   // Point coordinates array of the triangle
//   var triangleVertices = [
//      -1, -1, 0,    // bottom left
//       0, 0, 1,      // submit color: blue
//       1, -1, 0,    // bottom right
//       1, 1, 1,      // submit color: white
//       1, 1, 0,     // top right
//       1, 0, 0       // submit color: red
//   ];
   var triangleVertices = [
      -1,-1,-1,
      0,0,0,
      1,-1,-1,
      1,0,0,
      1,1,-1,
      1,1,0,
      -1,1,-1,
      0,1,0,
      -1,-1,1,
      0,0,1,
      1,-1,1,
      1,0,1,
      1,1,1,
      1,1,1,
      -1,1,1,
      0,1,1
   ];


   // Building Vertex Buffer Object - WebGL vertex array
   _triangleVertexBuffer = gl_ctx.createBuffer();                // *******
   gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleVertexBuffer);
   gl_ctx.bufferData(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(triangleVertices), gl_ctx.STATIC_DRAW);


   // Triangle faces array
   // var triangleFaces = [0, 1, 2];
   var triangleFaces = [
      0,1,2,
      0,2,3,
      4,5,6,
      4,6,7,
      0,3,7,
      0,4,7,
      1,2,6,
      1,5,6,
      2,3,6,
      3,7,6,
      0,1,5,
      0,4,5
   ];

   _triangleFacesBuffer = gl_ctx.createBuffer();                     // *******
   gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleFacesBuffer);
   gl_ctx.bufferData(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(triangleFaces), gl_ctx.STATIC_DRAW);
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_setMatrix () {
   _matrixProjection = MATRIX.getProjection(40, gl_canvas.width/gl_canvas.height, 1, 100);
   _matrixMovement = MATRIX.getIdentityMatrix();
   _matrixView = MATRIX.getIdentityMatrix();

   MATRIX.translateZ(_matrixView, zoomRatio);
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_draw() {
  if (animation) {
     window.cancelAnimationFrame(animation)
    }
   // set the color to transparent
   gl_ctx.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   // enable Depth buffer test and set depth buffer comparison function
   gl_ctx.enable(gl_ctx.DEPTH_TEST);
   gl_ctx.depthFunc(gl_ctx.LEQUAL);

   // set the clear value for the depth buffer to 1
   gl_ctx.clearDepth(1.0);

   var timeOld = 0;

   var animate = function (time) {
      var dAngle = rotationSpeed * (time - timeOld);

      if (X) {
         MATRIX.rotateX(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
      }
      if (Y) {
         MATRIX.rotateY(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
      }
      if (Z) {
         MATRIX.rotateZ(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
      }

      timeOld = time;

      // set the drawing area on the canvas and clear it
      gl_ctx.viewport(0.0, 0.0, gl_canvas.width, gl_canvas.height);
      gl_ctx.clear(gl_ctx.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl_ctx.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      // set projection matrix. _matrixProjection is not set yet.
      // It is a javascript array of 1 dimension with 16 floats
      gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_PosMatrix, false, _matrixProjection);
      gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_MovMatrix, false, _matrixMovement);
      gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_ViewMatrix, false, _matrixView);
      // drawing is here - use these points for next drawing
      // gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(variable, dimension, type, normalize, total vertex size in bytes, offset)
      gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(_position, 3, gl_ctx.FLOAT, false, 4*(3+3), 0);
      gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(_color, 3, gl_ctx.FLOAT, false, 4*(3+3), 3*4);

      gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleVertexBuffer);
      gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleFacesBuffer);

      // draw the triangle
      //gl_ctx.drawElements(gl_ctx.TRIANGLES, 3, gl_ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

      // draw cube
      gl_ctx.drawElements(gl_ctx.TRIANGLES, 6*2*3, gl_ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

      // drawing is finished - show the render
      gl_ctx.flush();
      // redraws the scene as soon as ready
      animation = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   };

   // launch animate for the first time
   animate(0);

}

var MATRIX = {
   degToRad: function(angle) {
      return (angle*Math.PI/180);
   },

   getProjection: function(angle, a, zMin, zMax) {
      var tan = Math.tan(MATRIX.degToRad(0.5*angle)),
         A=-(zMax+zMin)/(zMax-zMin),
            B=(-2*zMax*zMin)/(zMax-zMin);

      return [
          .5/tan,          0,   0,    0,
               0,   .5*a/tan,   0,    0,
               0,          0,   A,   -1,
               0,          0,   B,    0
      ]
   },

   getIdentityMatrix: function () {
      return [
         1, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 1, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 1, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 1
      ];
   },

   // rotate movement matrix with angle around X axis
   rotateX: function(movMat, angle) {
      var sin = Math.sin(angle);
      var cos = Math.cos(angle);
      var matElem1 = movMat[1],
          matElem5 = movMat[5],
          matElem9 = movMat[9];

      movMat[1] = movMat[1]*cos - movMat[2]*sin;
      movMat[5] = movMat[5]*cos - movMat[6]*sin;
      movMat[9] = movMat[9]*cos - movMat[10]*sin;

      movMat[2] = movMat[2]*cos + matElem1*sin;
      movMat[6] = movMat[6]*cos + matElem5*sin;
      movMat[10] = movMat[10]*cos + matElem9*sin;
   },

   // rotate movement matrix with angle around Y axis
   rotateY: function(movMat, angle) {
      var sin = Math.sin(angle);
      var cos = Math.cos(angle);
      var matElem0 = movMat[0],
          matElem4 = movMat[4],
          matElem8 = movMat[8];

      movMat[0] = movMat[0]*cos + movMat[2]*sin;
      movMat[4] = movMat[4]*cos + movMat[6]*sin;
      movMat[8] = movMat[8]*cos + movMat[10]*sin;

      movMat[2] = movMat[2]*cos - matElem0*sin;
      movMat[6] = movMat[6]*cos - matElem4*sin;
      movMat[10] = movMat[10]*cos - matElem8*sin;
   },

   // rotate movement matrix with angle around Z axis
   rotateZ: function(movMat, angle) {
      var sin = Math.sin(angle);
      var cos = Math.cos(angle);
      var matElem0 = movMat[0],
          matElem4 = movMat[4],
          matElem8 = movMat[8];

      movMat[0] = movMat[0]*cos - movMat[1]*sin;
      movMat[4] = movMat[4]*cos - movMat[5]*sin;
      movMat[8] = movMat[8]*cos - movMat[9]*sin;

      movMat[1] = movMat[1]*cos + matElem0*sin;
      movMat[5] = movMat[5]*cos + matElem4*sin;
      movMat[9] = movMat[9]*cos + matElem8*sin;
   },

   // translate movement matrix by trans along Z axis
   translateZ: function (movMat, trans) {
      movMat[14] += trans;
   }
};
```

```css
canvas#glcanvas {
   border: 1px solid #66666D;
   background-color: #545469;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form class="rotationCheckboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" id="rotateX"> X Rotation
    <input type="checkbox" id="rotateY"> Y Rotation
    <input type="checkbox" id="rotateZ"> Z Rotation
    <input type="button" value="Run" onclick="runWebGL()"/>
  </form>
  <canvas id="glcanvas" width="500" height="300">HTML5 canvas is not supported</canvas>
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where was the bug. Everything works perfect now.